# Parse or implode simple text in array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I have a simple array:

```
array(price => "1737 EUR - 3447 EUR")
```

And I need result just like this:

> $price1 = 1737
>
> $price = 3447

I know that is very simple question, but I don't know which function to choose and how to do it?

Comment: explode(); on "-" then intval(); on values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php
 $arr   = array("price" => "1737 EUR - 3447 EUR");
 preg_match('/(?P<price1>\d+)\s*EUR\s*-\s*(?P<price>\d+)\s*EUR/',$arr["price"],$matches);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well. But if I dump for example price1, the result is `price1 => "0 "` and I dont want to space behind zero. How can i fix this?

Comment: `trim` the sapce `trim($matches['price1'])`

Answer (score 0):

Or try this if you don't want to use regex;

```
$priceArray=array(price => "1737 EUR - 3447 EUR");
$spiltPrices=explode(' - ',$priceArray['price']);
echo $price1=$spiltPrices[0];
echo $price=$spiltPrices[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

not too pretty, but I would do something like this:

```
//the initial array
$price = array("price" => "1737 EUR - 3447 EUR");

$prices = explode("-",$price["price"]);
foreach($prices as &$price) $price = (int) $price;
print_r($prices); //Array ( [0] => 1737 [1] => 3447 )
```